# How to fix my popup that closes automatically after opening and refreshes my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I created a pop up in my HTML page but when I click my HTML element that launches the Popup, It appears for just second and it closes automatically and my page refreshes

Here's the detailed code that I'm using

HTML Code :

```
  <a class="lv-footer" id="openPop" href="">Visualiser plus de détails</a>
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
                    </div>
```

CSS code :

```
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaaaaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

and JS code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("openPop");

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
 btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
 }

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Can you tell me what's the problem ?

Comment: The default action for a link (`<a>`) is to navigate to the target mentioned by the `href` attribute. An `href` attribute without a target points per default to the actual document. You have to stop the default action of the link to prevent the reload of the page.

Comment: Also I guess you want `event.target !== modal` in the last eventListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("openPop");

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
 btn.onclick = function(event) {
 event.preventDefault()
modal.style.display = "block";
 }

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```css
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaaaaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="lv-footer" id="openPop" href="">Visualiser plus de détails</a>
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
                    </div>
```

Add `event.preventDefault()` on button click. which is anchor. So it will prevent the functionality of anchor tag that is redirecting.